# Apache is failing to start with mentioned error

Tags: apache, https, webserver, httpd.conf

I am enabled mod_ssl module in httpd.conf file and tried to enable ssl but now when I try to start `httpd`, getting below error

```
[webusr@web-node1 bin]$ ./apachectl -t
httpd: Syntax error on line 134 of /opt/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /opt/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ssl_cmd_SSLPassPhraseDialog
```

I have `mod_ssl.so` file under `/opt/httpd/modules` path but still I am facing this issue

Currently I am using `apache httpd 2.4.3 version` and I tried compiling `mod_ssl.so` file separately by using below commands

```
cd /path/to/httpd/source/modules/ssl
sudo /path/to/httpd/bin/apxs -c -i mod_ssl.c
```

After executing these steps I am getting a new `mod_ssl.so` file but not able to start `apache`

Comment: probably a mismatch between the openssl version httpd was compiled in vs the other version you have used to re-compile mod_ssl.

Comment: Now I tried without compiling mod_ssl module and I am getting this error

[webusr@web-node1 bin]$ sudo ./apachectl -t
httpd: Syntax error on line 134 of /opt/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /opt/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ERR_GET_FUNC

Any idea how to resolve this. I tried checking in multiple sites but not getting any resolution

Comment: Steps which I did to install apache 2.4.43
1. Downloaded 3.0.7 version and compiled it using below command
./Configure --prefix /opt/software/openssl/openssl-3.0.7 --openssldir=/opt/software/openssl/openssl-3.0.7 shared zlib
make
make install

2. I compiled httpd using this command
./configure --prefix=/opt/httpd --with-mpm=worker --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-connect -enable-proxy-http --enable-proxy-aip --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/opt/software/openssl/openssl-3.0.7 --with-apr=/opt/software/others/apr --with-apr-util=/opt/software/others/apr-util